Cleaning a stained carpet
About a week and a half ago, I had a deep clean done and the cleaner left a stain on the carpet outside of a bathroom. They weren't cleaning the carpet at the time, but my guess is something they used to clean the bathroom got on the carpet.
Here's a picture of it:

At night it's barely noticeable, but during the day it's quite yellowy.
The cleaning company says they can't clean bleach and said there's no point trying to steam clean. They've asked me to just replace the carpet.
Before I go commit to doing something like that, I just want to check if there's anything I could try.
Is it definitely bleach (I don't think they know for sure, it's just their best guess)? Can I try anything to see if it works? Should I try a steam cleaner?
Any help is much appreciated.

If the company has admitted it was their bleach that damaged the carpet, then ask them to replace the carpet, at their own expense. Don't try to clean it yourself.

@WeatherVane they didn't seem sure what it actually is, but are assuming bleach because of the colour. I am largely looking to see if others agree or whether it looks like it could be something cleanable. Replacing the carpet is quite a nuclear option for me since I don't have spare carpet anywhere in my home and replacing it for the entire room is quite cumbersome.

The post clearly says "the cleaner left a stain on the carpet".

Yes, I'm not sure where the confusion is sorry.

If this is about bleach, why would you think it could ever be fixed?

The bleach is known to leave yellowy spots (this is why baking soda is used in some situations as a whitening agent, when a yellowish tint is definitely not acceptable). And when bleach alters color, it also (kind of) destroys the material. So the short story is: you cannot just remove the spot.
Options:

Replace the carpet. You might be able to convince the company to replace it at their expense, they were not supposed to damage stuff.
Use diluted bleach to make the entire carpet yellowish.
Depending of the material in the carpet, the carpet might be suitable to be re-colored. But if the pigment will not properly stick to the carpet, you will return here to ask how to deal with the pigment making everything dirty in your house :)


Jokingly, you may remove that spot with scissors or with fire :) - but please do NOT do that.

Appreciate the detailed answer here, I'll mark this the answer unless I hear any convincing arguments to the contrary.

Hmmm.  Let's assume it is not bleach for a second.  It could be something else entirely.  I think the yellowish red could possibly be from rust.  Maybe they left a piece of eqipment there for a moment which was rusty on the bottom...or a tool box/bucket which had sat in a warehouse/van in a puddle of iron rust.  Maybe it IS bleach.  But before you go crazy on all the other options. maybe looks at some saner ones.  Whink is a great rust neutralizer and it could just be be applied then picked up with a larget wet sponge and blotted with a towel. If the carpet is natural fibers, you could also try Goof-off. It is ecellent at removing all types of stains (Do NOT use it on synthetic fibers. It will melt them)  There is also the possibilily of blotting in some diluted DAWN, letting it sit before pulling it up with a clean wet sponge. Certain motor oils are also that color. Lestoil (diluted) is excellent at removing greases and oils from fabrics...why not carpeting?  Before assuming IT IS DEF BLEACH....test that assumption is less damaging ways.  You could be surprised.
